# Helix aspersa or Cornu aspersum

Tags: zoology, taxonomy, molluscs

The common garden snail was originally assigned as *Helix aspersa* and stayed that way for over 200 years. Recently, some biologists assigned it to the genus or subgenus *Cornu* renaming it to *Cornu aspersum*, yet other researchers assigned it to *Cantareus*. Still, many texts still use the name *Helix aspersa*.

My question is what is the correct or official binomial nomenclature (scientific name) of the garden snail as for 2019?

Remark: I read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornu_aspersum) but even there there are inconsistencies about it. E.g. [Wikispecies](https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cantareus_aspersus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consulted with Prof. Henk Mienis, the curator of the Israeli Mollusca Collection, and the valid name is *Cornu aspersum*. The Israeli subspecies is *Cornu aspersum megalostomum*.

[image: Garden Snail in Israel]